# Transfer app from a scratch org

Tags: deployment

I've developed a flow app that includes:

- custom objects and custom page layouts and record types
- screen and autolaunched flows
- approval process
- process builder

So, I did it in my scratch org. What is the best way to save locally and move it to another org? I guess it should be a package or something like this.

Comment: Question, how was this scratch org created? Are you 100% sure you're in a scratch org and not in a sandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scratch orgs are designed for use with *source-driven development*, where the source of truth for your application is source code stored in version control.

There are a number of modules on Trailhead that teach the source-driven approach, such as [Develop an App with Salesforce CLI and Source Control](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/develop-app-with-salesforce-cli-and-source-control).

To quickly summarize, you'll use the `sfdx` CLI or the Visual Studio Code command palette to *retrieve source* to your local machine, which will extract the customizations you've created in the scratch org. You'll then be able to either deploy that source directly into another org (whether scratch org or persistent org), or choose to create a package. Packaging is not required to migrate changes, but it is available to you if you want to build a modular application, support upgrades, or deliver to external customers.